# Transposing dataframe in specific number of columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, transpose

I would like to transpose a dataframe with a specific structure. The dataframe looks something like this

```
Col1    Col2       Col3  Col4
NameA   PositionA  URLA  Firm1
NameB   PositionB  URLB  Firm1
NameC   PositionC  URLC  Firm2
NameD   PositionD  URLD  Firm3
NameE   PositionE  URLE  Firm3
...
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
Col4   Name1  Position1  URL1  Name2  Position2  URL2
Firm1  NameA  PositionA  URLA  NameB  PositionB  URLB
Firm2  NameC  PositionC  URLC  
Firm3  NameD  PositionD  ULRD  NameE  PositionE  URLE
...
```

So basically ordering the respective people per firm according to their name, position and url. The maximum of people I have for a firm (so rows per firm) is 49. Most firms have less than 49 rows, but I still want to have 49 columns per name, position and url and if a firm has less people than 49 the rest of the columns should be empty.

Is there any code where this can be done easily for a large dataset? I hope the question is worded understandably.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `pivot_wider`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat %>% 
  rename_with(~ c("Name", "Position", "URL", "Firm")) %>% 
  group_by(Firm) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = id, values_from = Name:URL, names_vary = "slowest", names_sep = "")


#   Firm  Name1 Position1 URL1  Name2 Position2 URL2 
# 1 Firm1 NameA PositionA URLA  NameB PositionB URLB 
# 2 Firm2 NameC PositionC URLC  NA    NA        NA   
# 3 Firm3 NameD PositionD URLD  NameE PositionE URLE
```